# Startup Order for varnishncsa

Tags: logging, varnish

I can't get varnishncsa to work at boot.  Once the server is running, I can do "service varnishncsa status" and it says it is running, but nothing is logged.  I have to use "service varnishncsa restart" to get it working.  I think varnishncsa is being started before varnishd is fully initialized.  What would be the best way to fix this?

I'm using Red Hat EL6.8 and Red Hat-packaged Varnish 2.1.5-5.  I've tried making varnishncsa load later by changing its chkconfig start order.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Varnish varnishncsa will wait for a while to see if the shared memory segment becomes available.

There are official packages of Varnish for EL6, perhaps upgrading is easiest.

Another option is of course to hack it; add `sleep 20` at the top of the init script.